# unable to start process bad code 502 bad gateway error dotnet.exe vs 2017

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have started a .net core angular web application using visual studio 2017 (Windows 7 machine).

Things were going well until I started hosting Jenkins on my local machine for a test. Now I am unable to start the project and I am getting this error:

unable to start process `c:\program files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe.` The web server failed with status code 502, Bad gateway.

The full response is not telling me much but here it is:

I have restarted VS studio, the machine, I HAVE reinstalled .net core twice and the problem persists. Any help is appreciated.
[the html file which has the full response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEY2x.png)
[Error received when I run the project using IIS express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blgSW.png)

Comment: And what does the error actually report in the file?

Comment: Try a different port?

Comment: As @Jammer said. It's possible Jenkins is using the port you've configured your project to use

Comment: I changed ports too and I stopped Jenkins..still same issue..

Comment: OK, Then you need to provide more detail, such as the contents of the file created with the error log in it.

Comment: I'm able to execute dotnet run from the commandline, but the server code is running on one port while the angular stuff is running on another.. not much in the logs say anything

Comment: but running without the debugger, the event viewer has this error:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/RESETAPP' with physical root 'C:\Users\xccc\source\repos\ResetApp\ResetApp\' failed to start process with commandline 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe -argFile "C:\Users\xccc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpB2EE.tmp"', ErrorCode = '0x800700c1 : 0.

Comment: any other ideas??...as of now, the workaround is to do dotnet.exe run from command line, and attaching the debugger from visual studio, but that's not sustainable since I would like backend and frontend to be integrated?

Comment: I have a similar problem but in the meantime to get around this problem I select the 'project' in contrast to 'IIS Express' to run my solution project; however I would not consider this a permanent solution to this problem.